# Matching only the first 3 letters of the computer names

Tags: vb.net

What I want to do is: if the first 3 letters of the computer name match something like "ZEB" or "DON" or "TIO" etc, etc, then do this and that. The only problem I am having is that the computer names out on the field are something like this "ZEB700" or "DON800" or "TIO900".

I only want to match/get the first three letters of the computer name I don't want to match/get the numbers after that.

What I currently have:

```
Dim strHostName As String
Dim Prefix As String

strHostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()
Prefix = strHostName.Substring(0, 3)
If Prefix = "ZEB" or "DON" or "TIO" Then
    MessageBox.Show("Matches")
End If
```

Comment: _If Prefix = "ZEB" orelse Prefix =  "DON" orelse Preifx =  "TIO" Then_ AND please explain if this is VB.NET or VBScript. They are two totally different languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with the `Or` syntax. Everything between `Or` or `OrElse` should be able to be evaluated to true or false, so `"POR" Or "MON"` doesn't make sense.You can do something like this if you have multiple groups of prefixes:

```
        Dim strHostName As String
        Dim Prefix As String

        Dim PrefixGroup1() As String = {"POR", "MON", "MTK"}

        strHostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()
        Prefix = strHostName.Substring(0, 3)


        If PrefixGroup1.Contains(Prefix) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Matches")
        End If
```

Or if you just have one group you can do this for shorthand:

```
        If {"POR", "MON", "MTK"}.Contains(Prefix) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Matches")
        End If
```

Or the long way:

```
        If Prefix = "POR" OrElse Prefix = "MON" OrElse Prefix = "MTK" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Matches")
        End If
```

Comment: You sexy human being, this worked out fantastically. I can't accept the answer yet until my partner tests this out on his end. Expect an accepted answer by sometime next week though. THANK YOUUUUUU!!!! :D

Answer (score 1):

The condition `Prefix = "ZEB" Or "DON" Or "TIO"` doesn't work the way you seem to expect. It does not compare the variable `Prefix` to either of the 3 strings, but tries to calculate the boolean expression `"ZEB" Or "DON" Or "TIO"` (which I'd expect to raise an error) and *then* compare the (boolean) result to the variable `Prefix`.

Change

```
If Prefix = "ZEB" or "DON" or "TIO" Then
```

to

```
If Prefix = "ZEB" Or Prefix = "DON" Or Prefix = "TIO" Then
```

and the problem will disappear.

An even better (more extensible) approach would be a regular expression match. Something like this should work:

```
Regex re = new Regex("^(DON|TIO|ZEB)")
If re.IsMatch(Prefix) Then
    ...
End If
```

Not exactly sure about the syntax, though, since I normally use VBScript, PowerShell and other scripting languages, not VB.net.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This seemed to have worked as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would do that with the Select Case structure:

```
Select Case strHostName.Substring(0, 3)
    Case "ZEB"
        MessageBox.Show("Matches")
   Case "DON"
        MessageBox.Show("Matches")
    Case "TIO"
        MessageBox.Show("Matches")
    Case Else
        MessageBox.Show("Does not match")
End Select
```

That lets you select different handling for each prefix.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with a select case construct like this:

```
Select Case strHostName.Substring(0, 3)
    Case "ZEB", "DON", "T10"
        MessageBox.Show("Matches")
    Case Else
        MessageBox.Show("Does not match")
End Select
```